# How to Search in Repos of Most copied/pasted Functions between multiple repos?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, code-duplication

Is there a way to find most copied/pasted functions or bulk of codes between multiple repos? For example, in react I'd rather make a component out of stuff copied around too many times and share between so when I update the component this copied function will take an impact everywhere. Otherwise function updated at one location will not be updated in an another location.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40799220/automated-refactoring-tool-to-find-similar-duplicate-source-code-for-java-javasc

Comment: But what if the names of the functions are different, but the code inside is exactly the same. What if the code in these functions does the same thing, but the variables are called something else? etc.

Comment: It'll be able to detect that as well. Most "code smell" or "mess detector" type linters are able to look for duplicate code chunks, even smaller ones, and point them out. They rely on the actual code, not function names or something. If the variable names are swapped out, it might not catch it, but if it is a large chunk and just the names are swapped, it probably will. Depends which one you are using though.